# How to echo multiple rows using mail()?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I've got stuck trying to echo multiple rows from a MySql database into the $message part of the email. The attached code only returns one result.

I want to send 1 email, in the email I want to output the 10 rows from the SQL query.
I actually receive the same email ten separate times rather than one email with ten rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stoic_quotes Order By rand() Limit 0,10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $to      = 'email@email.com';
    $subject = 'Daily Stoic Email';
    $message = $row["Maxim"]. "</br>";
    $headers = 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: email@email.om' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: *"How to echo multiple rows using mail()?"* - Huh? `mail()` doesn't know what your db looks like; title is unclear.

Comment: you need to replace the `$to` with the email row; I believe that's what you want to do here by sending out to multiple recipients, right?

Comment: Sorry, no I meant that $row["Maxim"] only returns one result when I receive the email.

Comment: Just to add, I actually receive the same email ten separate times rather than one email with ten rows.

Comment: Just to make it clear - you're sending yourself 10 emails with the value of $row['maxim']. Yes?

Comment: I want to send 1 email, in the email I want to output the 10 rows from the SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the mail call out of the loop

```
// don't select all (*) fields if you only need one
$sql = "SELECT Maxim FROM stoic_quotes Order By rand() Limit 0,10";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$message = '';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $message .= $row["Maxim"]. "</br>";
}

// prepare email headers
$to      = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'Daily Stoic Email';
$headers = 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: email@email.om' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// then send
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code but give this a try:

```
$to      = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'Daily Stoic Email';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM stoic_quotes Order By rand() Limit 0,10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$message = $row["Maxim"]. "</br>";
}
$headers = 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: email@email.om' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I have placed the to, subject, header and mail function out of the loop.

Cheers